# Code.org Addition Addition Not Working. Javascript

Tags: javascript, user-interface, code.org

I am trying to make a very simple system where I click a button and it adds the number of times clicked. The problem is, no matter what I try, I cant make the value go beyond the initial amount.
In this pic it says "1" repeatedly because its the sum of but_clicked+1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9vqE.png)

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: You want `but_clicked++` to increment the variable. There's no need for `x`.

Comment: `but_clicked = but_clicked + 1` or `but_clicked++` for short

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining but_clicked twice. It should only be written with var  at the beginning since it only needs to be defined once. Also, rather than having a whole separate variable for x, just do `but_clicked = but_clicked + 1;` or `but_clicked++;`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it a while ago but forgot to put up the solution
I had basically defined the variable twice

now that I am looking at it again it's just as @yxtoa said "You're defining but_clicked twice"

this is the code I finalized

```
var but_clicked = 0;
function help() {
  but_clicked = but_clicked + 1;
  console.log(but_clicked);
}
```